# save to local file data from html form as json

Tags: python

i am new in flask/python,
i have this sample html form,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

i need  the "submit" button to pass all data  from the form  ad variables in json format and save it on folder and then to run ansible play-book with --extra variables to use the data from  the file , can this be done?
many many thanks friends

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

1. Yes, this can be done.
2. How? 
   2.1 In the HTML page, a submit button as show her

   https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp#:~:text=The%20Submit%20Button,in%20the%20form's%20action%20attribute.

   2.2 In the Flask/python script. Use a `request` module to collect the response and prepare a `dict` object to save in json.
3. Since you are a beginner in Flask, I request you to check the following blog. Must see the first 5 beginner pages.

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins

Happy Learning!